# Import Custom Labels in non-standard Language?

Tags: translation, language, translation-workbench

We use a series of Custom Labels in our application and want to translate for a specific language (e.g. Indian or Catalan).

But when I go to the translation workbench, those languages are not available to activate. How can we translate our Custom Labels to those languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label translations can only be defined for languages that Salesforce supports. [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_translations.htm)

Ultimately though, labels are displayed based on a user's language settings, so even if you could define a translation for a non-standard language, there would be no way to have it displayed to the user.

I suppose the only workaround would be to define the translation as the language that your users would be using instead.